# use of 'n' before deduction of 'auto' C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to have my function return 3 values (n, down and across) I've read online how 'auto' can be used but must be doing something wrong.
The function takes in a 2D vector of integers (as well as other variables) and checks for how many numbers are connected to board[0][0] such that they are the same number.
I've tried putting auto in front of the function inside the function itself, tried leaving it blank, tried just having chain = chainNodes(...) but I always seem to get an error. Here's the code:

```
tuple<int, int, int> chainNodes(vector<vector<int>> board, int originalNum,
                                unsigned int across, unsigned int down, int ijSum,
                                int n)
{
    struct chain {
        int n, down, across;
    };

    if(down + across > ijSum) {
        ijSum = down + across;
    } else if((down + across == ijSum) &&
              ((down - across) * (down - across) < (ijSum) * (ijSum))) {
        ijSum = down + across;
    }

    board[down][across] = 0;
    n += 1;

    // Check below
    if((down != (board.size() - 1)) && (board[down + 1][across]) == originalNum) {
        down += 1;
        auto [n, iPoint, jPoint] = chainNodes(board, originalNum, across, down, ijSum, n);
        down -= 1;
    }
    // Check right, up and left (I've removed so its not too messy here)

    return chain{n, down, across};
}
```

Sorry, I forgot to include the error message.
error: use of 'n' before deduction of 'auto'
It occurs on the line that uses auto.

Comment: `return {n, down, across};`

Comment: What error(s) do you get? Include the error message as part of the question

Comment: do you want to return a `tuple` or an instance of `chain`?

Comment: `auto [n,` - you already have a variable called `n` in this function, you are trying to declare another one with the same name (and apparently it confuses your compiler)

Comment: Elijay I've just tried that and that hasn't changed anything?

Comment: The destructuring `auto [n, iPoint, jPoint] = chainNodes(board, originalNum, across, down, ijSum, n);` is not using any of the results.  Intentional?  The `n` cannot be reused, so should be renamed `nn`.

Comment: idclev 463035818 I'm just trying to return the 3 values [n,down,across] so however I can do that I suppose?

Comment: `auto [nn, iPoint, jPoint] = ...` and then `n = nn` if that's really what you want.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: or `n = std::get<0>(/*...*/);`.

Comment: Why are you using a `tuple` when you have a nice named struct?

Comment: @cigien Good point. The struct should be defined outside the function and the function should return a `chain`.

Comment: Elijay, I'm not sure I know what you mean by none of the results are being used? The function returns [n,down,across] and I have a line inside main() as follows: "auto [n, iPoint, jPoint] = chainNodes(board, originalNum, across, down, ijSum, n];" that I hope would be saving the returned values to n, iPoint and jPoint?

Comment: `if ((down + across == ijSum) && /*..*/) {
        ijSum = down + across;
    }` seems strange: it does assignation with same value, so noop...

Comment: None of the  `auto [n, iPoint, jPoint] = ...` variables are being used. They are declared at block scope and the block ends before you do anything with them.

Comment: @Jarod42 The function checks to see if the new location (down,across) has the same total as a previous location, then I want to take the location whereby down and across is closest. I.e. (4,4) and (5,3) I'd want to take (4,4) if you follow?

Comment: ok, you dont care that much whether it is a tuple or a `chain`, nevertheless you should decide ;) that is one problem in your code: function is declared to return a tuple, you try to return a `chain`, cannot work

Comment: btw if your quesiton is only about how to return three values from the function you could remove all the other stuff from the code to make it a minimal example. See [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

Issue with

```
auto [n, iPoint, jPoint] = chainNodes(board, originalNum, across, down, ijSum, n);
```

is similar to

```
auto n = foo(n); // `foo(n)` uses `n` from `auto n`,
                 // not the one from outer scope as function parameter
```

The construct `int a = a + 1;` is legal **but** lead to UB as reading uninitialized variable.

That kind of construct allows legal and valid behavior `void* p = &p;`.

Your code has other errors and it is not clear for me expected behavior of the function.

So not sure if following is the correct fix, but you might want:

```
n = std::get<0>(chainNodes(board, originalNum, across, down, ijSum, n));
```

Comment: I think OP expects the `n` in `auto [n` to be the same `n` as `chainNodes` was called with.  Neither `g++` nor `clang++` warns about the shadowing declaration strangely enough.